# How to drag and drop rows in NSTableView in Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have struck with one point i.e now I have got a list of data using NSTableView but what my requirement is, able to drag and drop that rows from one row position to another row position. please give any suggestion for get out this problem. Thanks in advance.[image]

[My sample code](https://slack-files.com/T195TPN3W-F45H3UT89-fc2ca99061)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `NSTableViewDataSource` subclass implement `WriteRows`,  `ValidateDrop` and `AcceptDrop` and register which Drag/Drop targets your `NSTableView` accepts. In this case you are only accepting Drops from within your own `NSTableView`.

#### Assign a name that will be used for valid drag operations on this `NSTableView`:

```
// Any name can be registered, I find using the class name 
// of the items in the datasource is cleaner than a const string
string DragDropType = typeof(Product).FullName;
```

#### Register the drag types for your `NSTableView`:

```
ProductTable.RegisterForDraggedTypes(new string[] { DragDropType });
```

### Implement drag/drop methods on your `NSTableViewDataSource`:

```
public override bool WriteRows(NSTableView tableView, NSIndexSet rowIndexes, NSPasteboard pboard)
{
    var data = NSKeyedArchiver.ArchivedDataWithRootObject(rowIndexes);
    pboard.DeclareTypes(new string[] { DragDropType }, this);
    pboard.SetDataForType(data, DragDropType);
    return true;
}

public override NSDragOperation ValidateDrop(NSTableView tableView, NSDraggingInfo info, nint row, NSTableViewDropOperation dropOperation)
{
    tableView.SetDropRowDropOperation(row, dropOperation);
    return NSDragOperation.Move;
}

public override bool AcceptDrop(NSTableView tableView, NSDraggingInfo info, nint row, NSTableViewDropOperation dropOperation)
{
    var rowData = info.DraggingPasteboard.GetDataForType(DragDropType);
    if (rowData == null)
        return false;
    var dataArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.UnarchiveObject(rowData) as NSIndexSet;
    Console.WriteLine($"{dataArray}");
    // Move hack for this example... you need to handle the complete NSIndexSet
    tableView.BeginUpdates();
    var tmpProduct = Products[(int)dataArray.FirstIndex];
    Products.RemoveAt((int)dataArray.FirstIndex);
    if (Products.Count == row - 1)
        Products.Insert((int)row - 1 , tmpProduct);
    else 
        Products.Insert((int)row, tmpProduct);
    tableView.ReloadData();
    tableView.EndUpdates();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help. I don't understand register drag drop type. now I have register drag drop type in my View Controller and when try to write that DragDropType string in accept drop method it shows error. please help me to how to resolve it.

Comment: --> My table accept that method but what my problem is you have taken 'DragDropType' string and insert some value, there you have write 'typeof(product).FullName' in that what is product and another issue this registerdrag type code write in View Controller right? but 'DragDropType' is not appear in my datasourcetable. I am very new to this, please help me.

Comment: I am creating NSTableView in .XIb and I am not declare any array controller to  mytable.

Comment: So, as my understanding 'product' is the class name of our table datasource right? and I have confused with 'DragDropType' string. I have assigned 'typeof' value in my view controller, my 'writ row' method is present in tableview datasource class, then how can I get that string value.

Comment: OK, thank you. I have tried but when the compile time my application should be closed. I have tried to find out the problem but con't get it. I have post a my sample code, please refer that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135827/discussion-between-deepak-and-sushihangover).

Comment: great to hear it... ;-)

Comment: I have a simple problem while dragging i.e dragging the items only on by pressing cursor on empty space between cross and button when I tried to drag the item on button it's not dragged. how can I drag items on buttons.

Comment: Another problem is it drag only one row position at a time. If want to move fourth index row to first index row but it move only third index only. I want to replace the row where I can drop the row.

Comment: @Deepak Change the remove/insert logic based upon the `NSIndexSet` and dropped `row` parameter to match your requirements, the code example is just a sample, you need to factor it to your data.

Comment: @Deepak Typically you provide a drag area in the cell that the user presses/holds while dragging since "active" UI elements will block the begin drag event, consult Apple doc : Figure 5-2 and the description under it : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html There are a number of ways to work around this, but you will have to handle all the cell's events and pass them around...